# When switching tabs through the chrome extension, how to store the title of the respective tabs in an array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to collect and store tab titles through chrome extension. Therefore, even when switching tabs, it is necessary to store the title  array of the first tab and other tabs and finally return the title of the first tab. The function I am currently using as follows. But when the tab is changed, the title of the first tab us replaced by second (changed) title. How to store the relevant title in an array? Can it be done only through a content script?

**contentScript.js**

```
    var pageTitleRegxArray = ["li[class*=selected][class*=tab]", 
    "li[class*=active][class*=tab]", "li[class*=Selected][class*=menu]", 
    "li[class*=selected][class*=menu]", "li[class*=active][class*=menu]", 
    "span[class*=title]","span[class*=Title]"];
    
    
    function getPageInfor() {
        var titles = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < pageTitleRegxArray.length; i++) {
            var title = document.querySelectorAll('' + pageTitleRegxArray[i] + '');
            if (title[0]) {
                var currentTitle = title[0].innerText || title[0].textContent;
                currentTitle = currentTitle.trim();
                if(currentTitle){
                  titles.push(currentTitle);
                }
            }
        }
        if (titles.length == 0) {
           titles.push(document.title);
        }
        return titles;
    }
```

Comment: put console.log or debugger to see if the "if" checks are true.

Comment: How is if check true relevant?  Even if none of the above if's are true, the title is obtained in the last if, so it's not a problem, right?

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood the question. For more clarification, you want to store all the tab titles in a window right? because contentScripts are tab specific it can only get the tab's title which it is in. So, you can use `chrome.tabs` API in background script and get the tab titles in content script by messaging background script.

Edit: Please elaborate if I understood wrong again.

Comment: Yes you are right.  I tried to get this data through the content script itself.  The reason is that a problem arises when retrieving the data content to the script through the background.  Apparently, the background is involved in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chrome.tabs` and `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` API. You can send a message from content script to background script and get the tabs' title in response.

content-script.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: get_tab_title}, function(response){
 if(response.titles){
  var titles = response.titles;
 }
});
```

backgorund-script.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
 if(request.action == "get_tab_title"){
  var titles = [];
  chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){    // gets all tabs
   for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
    titles.push(tabs[0].title);
   }
   sendResponse({titles: titles});
  }
  return 1; //returning 1 because we are sending response async-ly (refer documentaion)
 }
});
```

So, mostly you would have to split your `getPageInfor()` function or handle by returning [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).